# ThemeData primaryColor is not work in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter 2.5.2 and  primaryColor is not working for me, I want to use hexcode of color, what am I doing wrong here,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'input_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(BMICalculator());

class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFFCF3D10),
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a transition(WIP) to `ColorScheme`s for theming. You can read about it here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89839#issuecomment-919437144

IMO ColorSchemes are not yet complete, you can use `primarySwatch` property of ThemeData to do what you're trying to achive.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mayank for the issue link, from reading all the comments from this official issue [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89839#issuecomment-919437144) I noticed

They did this intentionally as part of [Theme System cleanup](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kzIOQN4QYfVsc5lMZgy_A-FWGXBAJBMySGqZqsJytcE/edit#heading=h.pub7jnop54q0) and to make everything more consistent and based off the ColorScheme colors.

Flutter team has mentioned clearly that they will eventually be moving all components away from `ThemeData.primaryColor`

and this can be fixed by providing a color scheme with the same primary color that you desire:

```
    theme: ThemeData(
     primaryColor: ColorsX.primary,
     colorScheme: ColorScheme.light().copyWith(primary: ColorsX.primary),
  );
```

for me this was the solution :

```
 theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Color(0xffcf3d10)),
```

Now the things works as intdended for me.